# How do I configure the iDRAC on a static IP?

Tags: dell-poweredge, configuration-management, drac, colocation

I have a Dell PowerEdge R610 in colocation. When I set it up at home, the machine was assigned two IP's from my router (using DHCP): one for the OS and one for the iDRAC. Now that the server is in colocation, I have a very annoying problem...

I have two IP's for this server: .77 and .78. I want to use .77 for the OS and .78 for the iDRAC. So I assigned this IP as static IP in the BIOS for the iDRAC. I am using iDRAC Express, so I can't use a dedicated NIC. Therefore, I setup a shared NIC. That would require NIC teaming from the OS (CentOS 7). So I installed `racadm` and executed:

```
racadm setniccfg -s serverip2 subnet gw
```

Rebooted the server, but when I access the second IP it just shows content from the web server (so it doesn't route to the iDRAC but to the OS).

I'm probably making an incredibly stupid mistake... But what is going wrong here?

Comment: An ifconfig return what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've assigned that IP to the server itself within it's network stack (i.e. if you're using windows then you set the IP on one of the network cards from within the settings of one of the network cards). The DRAC and the host are two seperate devices, you can't specify it in the OS and on the DRAC as they will clash. If the .78 IP is **just** to be used for DRAC then ensure it is not set in the OS. If you need the .78 for both the OS and the DRAC then you're out of luck, find another spare IP and assign that to the drac with racadm instead of .78.

Comment: I could definitely remove the .78 IP from the OS (CentOS). So you're saying that if I do that my iDRAC will be reachable from that IP?

Comment: Yes. Imagine the idrac as it's own computer (because that's what it is). If you had two centos boxes with the same IP on the same subnet you would be seeing the same problem. Where the traffic reaches is dependent on which server responds to an ARP request first.

Comment: The idea of an idrac is to have an IP that's independant of a host machine so that, if it goes down, you can connect to the console on the idrac and bring it back up.

Comment: Done - it kinda works. When the OS is not active, I can access the iDRAC. When the OS is active, I can't access the iDRAC anymore, even though the iDRAC IP is not configured anywhere in the OS.

Comment: I think you probably need to flush the arp table on the machine you're trying to access them from. What OS are you connecting from?

Comment: I'm connecting from an OS X machine.

Comment: try sudo arp -a -d from a terminal to clear the arp cache, then test again. If it's still broken thereafter then the centos box must still have the IP assigned somehow, try ifconfig or ip addr from the centos box to make doubley sure it's not still holding the IP. Also, are you link-local to this machine or are you routing to it remotely? If the latter, the arp -a -d trick on your mac won't work.

Comment: I just reinstalled the OS and only configured the first IP. This works perfectly. Thanks Alex!!!

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding the port number to the web address? For example https://192.168.1.78:5900

Comment: I originally didn't, but doing so also doesn't work. This should be a comment btw!